# Where should DFS Role be installed?

Tags: dfs

I've been searching for best practices on "where to install DFS role ?".

Is there any recommandation about this ? Is there a "best way" to do it ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Need more information - such as which OS?

Answer (score 2):

On the file servers that will be hosting replicated shares or namespaces.